# I'm aging a few bottles. They've been in the fridge for a while. Should I take them out now?

Tags: temperature, aging, age

Pretty much this. I'm storing/aging bottles. They've been in my fridge for 6+ months now. I want to leave them there at least another 6+ months and on. But I've read aging beers in fridge is a "bad" idea because the cork will dry up. (All my bottles have corks). Temperature in the fridge is just above 32F (0 celsius)

I've talked to my father recently who's more into wine and told me I should get them out of the fridge and leave them somewhere else. That somewhere else is pitch black, pretty much on a cool floor and ambient temperature is about [65F(18 celsius), 85% humidity](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NGwnG.jpg)

[image: Temperature and Humidity]

Is there a risk to change the ambient temperature while it is aging, am I better getting them out of the fridge or does it matter little. I have a few bottles I've left out of the fridge in that place already. Should they go into the fridge? I'm also a bit curious as to why as well how it would affect the beers.

Answer (score 5):

I believe the general principal is that lower temperatures will result in slower (or negligible) aging process than warmer temperatures. The results will certainly vary depending on the ABV and other qualities of the beer. Storing bottles horizontally should prevent the corks from drying.

Answer (score 2):

Remember, that not all of the beers are suitable for aging. Mainly porter beer can be stored beyond expiration date (30 years!), but some others too. And i see no point for aging beer in a fridge.

Comment: According to the brewers, they can age a few years.

Answer (score 1):

It won't hurt the beer to take it out of the fridge.  Work done by Dr. Charles Bamforth has suggested that every extra 10 degrees Celcius of temperate cuts doubles the speed of beer deterioration.  So, if you pull them out and store them at cellar temp (~55 F), they'll age about twice as fast.  Dark is definitely good. Higher humidity vertical storage is preferential to horizontal storage in a bottle conditioned beer, as you'll want particulate settling in the bottom.

You can see an interview with Charlie [here](http://beersmith.com/blog/2014/01/31/flavor-stability-in-beer-with-dr-charlie-bamforth-beersmith-podcast-74/).

Answer (score 0):

That sounds pretty much like an ideal place to store and age beer and wine. 65F is maybe a tad on the warm side, but nowhere near the temperatures that would actually cook the beer and be harmful to it.

There is no harm in taking the bottles out from the fridge and in to your "cellar". And yes, leaving them in the fridge will not be good from an aging point of view and yes, the corks are likely to dry out in the fridge.